# Javascript syntax error in IE11 for sort function

Tags: javascript, sorting, internet-explorer

I am sorting an Array with Javascript and it is working fine in Chrome, Firefox, Safari but in IE11 I am getting a syntax error. Anyone know what could be causing this? Here's my sort function:

```
arr.sort((a, b) => b - a);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer 11 does not support the ES2015 feature [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Either use the `function` syntax or incorporate a transpiler such as [Babel](https://babeljs.io) or [TypeScript](https://typescriptlang.org) into your toolchain.

[Your code as transpiled by Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=G4QwTgBOkLwQ2gVgDQQEyoCwF0DcAofaAOgGcB7MAFwAoaRUAjASghgD4JGIBaKZ3EA&debug=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.0.0-alpha.19)

[Your code as transpiled by TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=1#code/G4QwTgBOkLwQ2gVgDQQEyoCwF0DcBYAKCOgDoBnAezABcAKOkVAIwEoIYA+CZiAWiitcQA)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, `function` worked great!